# Underlining subsections / subsubsections in LaTeX with ulem?

Tags: latex

I want to underline subsubsections in the way shown in the example below with the `uwave` method of the `ulem` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4, numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Sections   
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setkomafont{section}{\bfseries \sffamily\LARGE}    
\setkomafont{subsection}{\bfseries \sffamily \large}    
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{ \bfseries \sffamily}   

\renewcommand\sectionformat{\makebox[0pt][r]{\color{Green}\thesection\autodot\enskip}}
\renewcommand\subsectionformat{\color{Green}\thesubsection\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand\subsubsectionformat{\color{Green} \thesubsubsection\autodot\enskip} %or \enskip



%UNDERLINED SUBSECTIONS     
\usepackage{ulem}
\normalem  
\newcommand\subsectionuline{%   
    \bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{Green}{\rule[-.55ex]{1pt}{.5pt}}}
    \ULon%    
}         
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\subsectionuline}




\begin{document}       
\section{The section}    
\subsection{The subsection}    
 
\subsubsection{This should be underlined with a \uwave{wave}}
    \end{document}
```

I have already manged to redefine the \subsection to be underlined with a straight rule-
I am using KOMA classes, which are sadly not compatible with the *titlesec* package. So what is the best way to make these "curly" rules with KOMA classes?

[image: Example of how it should look like]

The `\rule` command can unfortunately not be replaced with the `\uwave` as emphasized with the `\subsectionuline` command...

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\uwave}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4, numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Sections   
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setkomafont{section}{\bfseries \sffamily\LARGE}    
\setkomafont{subsection}{\bfseries \sffamily \large}    
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{ \bfseries \sffamily}   

\renewcommand\sectionformat{\makebox[0pt][r]{\color{Green}\thesection\autodot\enskip}}
\renewcommand\subsectionformat{\color{Green}\thesubsection\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand\subsubsectionformat{\color{Green} \thesubsubsection\autodot\enskip} %or \enskip



%UNDERLINED SUBSECTIONS     
\usepackage{ulem}
\normalem  
\newcommand\subsectionuline{%   
    \bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{Green}{\rule[-.55ex]{1pt}{.5pt}}}
    \ULon%    
}         
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\subsectionuline}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\uwave}


\begin{document}       
\section{The section}    
\subsection{The subsection}    
 
\subsubsection{This should be underlined with a \uwave{wave}}

test

\section{The section}    
\subsection{The subsection}    

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I feel so dumb right now. Many thanks to you! That's exactly the result I desired. 
I din't know It was that easy with the KOMA classes. If you look for replies to questions othere people asked, it rather seems like the majority tends to utilise the "regular" classes...

Comment: @ManuelManUser No need to feel dumb, my first solution to your problem included messing with internal koma script functions like `\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip #2 \uwave{#3}}{\uwave{#4}}%
}` -- the easy solution is not always the obvious solution :)

Comment: @ManuelManUser Koma script is very niche -- you don't find many users outside of Germany.